# How to perform string replacement in a JMeter HTTP Request Body Data field?

Tags: jmeter

I'm using this in the Body Data field in the HTTP Request sampler to read an XML from a file

```
{"messagePayload":"${__FileToString(${ProjectHome}/Sample Messages/Request.xml)}"}
```

Now I need to escape double quotes to be a valid JSON, I can't find a JMeter function that does that, for example:

```
{"messagePayload":"${__FileToString(${ProjectHome}/Sample Messages/Request.xml).replace('"', '\"'}"}
```

I wish to find a solution that works with the Body Data field, without having to write a separate script for it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is **really** what you're looking for:

You can use either [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) configured like:

```
${__groovy(new File(vars.get('ProjectHome') + '/Sample Messages/Request.xml').text.replaceAll('"'\,'\\\\\\\\"'),)}
```

or consider using [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup). It's available via [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) bundle which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

```
${__strReplace(${__FileToString(${ProjectHome}/Sample Messages/Request.xml)},\",\\\",)}
```

However I think you should rather go for [__escapeXml()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__escapeXml) or [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-) depending on what you're trying to achieve